# Pixel Check With Node.js

Tags: javascript, coordinates, node.js

I'm trying to check if a pixel of a certain color at (x,y) has moved within a boundary of [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)] and also update its new position to console. I'm doing this as a desktop application so no html canvas. Also I'm not sure how to define a boundary in this manner.

Comment: If you're not using canvas, then what do you use for display?

Comment: Could this be done using raycasting?

Comment: Do you even know what ray casting is?

Comment: Yes, are you familiar with autoit or autohot key?